# How to update one column using a DropDownList inside a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am struggling with updating a column in the GridView with a DropDownList. In details, I have a GridView that I am using it to add, delete and update/edit the employees information. This information is employee Username, Name, BadgeNo, JobTitle, and the DivisionShortcut. The Divisions will be listed in a DropDownList, but still I cannot update this column and I don't know why.

I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name, JobTitle, BadgeNo, IsActive, DivisionCode
Divisions Table: SapCode, DivisionShortcut
```

I wrote the code and I don't find any error during debugging the code. However, when I run the code and selected one of the values from the dropdownlist, the column doesn't update and I don't know why. So how to get this column updated inside the GridView?

ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Username" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#DEBA84" 
             CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" BorderStyle="None" 
             BorderColor="#DEBA84" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
             OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
             OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
            <FooterStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
              BackColor="#F7DFB5"></FooterStyle>
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
              HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
              BackColor="#A55129"></HeaderStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true"
                                EditImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" UpdateImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" 
                                CancelImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("DivisionShortcut")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DivisionsList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DivisionsListDataSource"
                                          AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="DivisionShortcut" DataValueField="SapCode"
                                          selectedValue='<%# Bind("DivisionShortcut") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Network ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Name")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("JobTitle")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtJobTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobTitle")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Badge No.">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("BadgeNo")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBadgeNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BadgeNo")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("IsActive")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" 
                                      Checked='<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString().Equals("True") %>'/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkB" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" CommandName="Delete" />
                        </span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UsersInfoDBConnectionString %>" 

            SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut,dbo.employee.DivisionCode dbo.employee.Username, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.employee.JobTitle, dbo.employee.BadgeNo, dbo.employee.IsActive
                FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                            dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [employee] SET [Name] = @Name, [JobTitle] = @JobTitle, 
                                                [BadgeNo] = @BadgeNo WHERE [Username] = @Username"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [employee] WHERE [Username] = @Username">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String"  />
                <asp:Parameter Name="JobTitle" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="BadgeNo" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**And outside the GridView, I have the SqlDataSource for the DropDownList:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DivisionsListDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UsersInfoDBConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Divisions"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Divisions] ([SapCode], [DivisionShortcut]) VALUES (@SapCode, @DivisionShortcut)"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Divisions] SET [DivisionShortcut] = @DivisionShortcut WHERE [SapCode] = @SapCode">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="SapCode" Type="Double" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="SapCode" Type="Double" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionShortcut" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionShortcut" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SapCode" Type="Double" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code-Behind:

```
//For editing any row in the GridView
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) 
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    }

    //For canceling any editng in any row in the GridView
    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    }

    //For updating the information in any row in the GridView
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvrow = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        DropDownList DivisionsList = (DropDownList)gvrow.FindControl("DivisionsList"); 

        TextBox txtEmployeeName = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtEmployeeName");
        TextBox txtJobTitle = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtJobTitle");
        TextBox txtBadgeNo = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtBadgeNo");

        CheckBox isActive = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("isActive");

        //For getting the ID (primary key) of that row
        string username = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        string name = txtEmployeeName.Text;
        string jobTitle = txtJobTitle.Text;
        string badgeNo = txtBadgeNo.Text;
        string division = DivisionsList.Text;
        //string divisioncode = DivisionsList.SelectedValue;

        UpdateEmployeeInfo(username, name, jobTitle, badgeNo, division);
    }


    private void UpdateEmployeeInfo(string username, string name, string jobTitle, string badgeNo, string division)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersInfoDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string update = @"UPDATE Employee SET Name = @Name, JobTitle = @JobTitle, 
                            BadgeNo = @BadgeNo WHERE Username = @Username";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", jobTitle);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BadgeNo", badgeNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@division", division);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SapCode", divisioncode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", isActive.checked);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    //For deleting a row in the GridView
    protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) 
    {
        string networkID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersInfoDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string deleteCommand = "DELETE employee where dbo.employee.Username = " + networkID;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteCommand, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", networkID);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException se)
        {
            throw se;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: your problem still not solved :(

Answer (score 0):

`string division = DivisionsList.Text;`This is wrong you have to pass the SapCode because SapCode is your primary key in Divison table and it is the foreing key in the Employees table so you have to update the SapCode in your Employee table. Hope that it will work.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string division = DivisionsList.Value; // Hope that it will work
}
```

Comment: ok but this is a mistake in your code. Are you getting the DivisionsList.Value in the codebehind ? Do you check it

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void ddlGrdDtype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList btn = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.Parent.Parent;
        int i = row.RowIndex;

      

        Label lbl_LAId = (Label)grdAttendance.Rows[i].FindControl("lblLAId");
        Label lbl_AttendanceDate = (Label)grdAttendance.Rows[i].FindControl("lblAttendanceDate");
        lblAttandanceDate.Value = lbl_AttendanceDate.Text;
        Label lbl_WorkHrs = (Label)grdAttendance.Rows[i].FindControl("lblWorkHrs");
        Label lbl_Duties = (Label)grdAttendance.Rows[i].FindControl("lblDuties");
        DropDownList ddlGrdDtype = (DropDownList)grdAttendance.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlGrdDtype");
        lblLAId.Value = lbl_LAId.Text;
       

        UpdateDutyTypeOnSelection(lbl_LAId.Text, lbl_WorkHrs.Text, lbl_Duties.Text, ddlGrdDtype.SelectedItem.Text);
    }
```